# Teradata macro with volatile table and CTE to insert data into a table

Tags: teradata

I need to create a teradata macro to extract information into a volatile table first, then do CTE to extract data from this volatile table and insert into a teradata table, tried different ways all fail, appreciate help!

```
CREATE MACRO database.macro_insertion_tablename AS (

  CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt AS
  (
     SELECT
       id, bu,
       CONCAT(TO_CHAR(comment_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), ' ', action) AS full_action,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as cnt
     FROM database.table1
  ) WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(id, row_num) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 

  WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, bu, act, rn) AS
  (
     SELECT 
       id, bu
       ,CAST(full_action AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS full_action
       ,row_num
     FROM vt
     WHERE row_num = cnt

     UNION ALL

     SELECT
       vt.id, vt.bu 
       ,cte.act || ' / ' || vt.full_action
       ,vt.row_num
     FROM vt
     JOIN cte On vt.id = cte.id AND vt.row_num = cte.rn - 1
  )  

  INSERT INTO database.table (id, bu, full_action)
  SELECT id, bu, act
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1;

  DROP TABLE vt; 
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by fail?  Is it an error or you're not seeing what you're expecting? 
 What results are you expecting and what are you currently getting?

Comment: Remember a volatile table like you defined is only available to the session that creates it.

Comment: Aside from specifying the distribution of the result set (`id, row_num`) is there a particular reason why you need are using a volatile table?  Can't you just incorporate your volatile table's result set as a secondary `CTE` in your `INSERT INTO database.table ... ` statement?

Answer (score 1):

DDL must be the *only* statement in a Teradata Macro.

As workaround you could switch to a *Global Temporary Table* which is defined once and then you simply Insert/Select into it instead of CREATE VOLATILE TABLE.

But in your case there's no need for a temp table plus inefficient recursive processing to get a "group concat":

```
SELECT id, max(bu) -- maybe min(bu)?
   XmlAgg(Concat(To_Char(comment_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), ' ', action)
          ORDER BY comment_date)  (VARCHAR(5000)) AS full_action
FROM database.table1
GROUP BY 1
```

will give you a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comments, you should be able to define multiple CTEs in the same statement.  It may be tricky getting the `RECURSIVE CTE` to work, but it sounds like it's possible.  Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE MACRO database.macro_insertion_tablename AS (

  WITH vt (id, bu, full_action, row_num, cnt) AS
  (
     SELECT
       id, bu,
       CONCAT(TO_CHAR(comment_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), ' ', action) AS full_action,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as cnt
     FROM database.table1
  ),
  RECURSIVE cte (id, bu, act, rn) AS
  (
     SELECT 
       id, bu
       ,CAST(full_action AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS full_action
       ,row_num
     FROM vt
     WHERE row_num = cnt

     UNION ALL

     SELECT
       vt.id, vt.bu 
       ,cte.act || ' / ' || vt.full_action
       ,vt.row_num
     FROM vt
     JOIN cte On vt.id = cte.id AND vt.row_num = cte.rn - 1
  )  

  INSERT INTO database.table (id, bu, full_action)
  SELECT id, bu, act
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1;
);
```

I don't have a `Teradata` system to test with, so not 100% it will work as-is, but give it a try.  You may need to change `RECURSIVE` to `WITH RECURSIVE` and also the ordering of the `CTE` queries (i.e. put the `RECURSIVE` one first).  Take a look at these two links:

[Teradata Forum - Multiple With Clause](https://community.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=8dc6c7ef1b57fb00682ca8233a4bcb05)
[teradata Forum - Common Table Expressions](https://community.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=c258c3671b97fb00682ca8233a4bcba2)

Comment: thank you, but not working, looks macro cannot do insert. I will try SP see if it works.

Comment: What happens when you run the query by itself outside the macro?  Try breaking down the individual `SELECT` queries to see if they are each returning the rows you expect.

Comment: tried not working, just `select` is fine, but `insert into... select ... ` is not working. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Is there an error or are there no rows being `INSERT`ed into your table?  Please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: I work it out, the correct syntax to insert into teradata for recursive table is `insert into table with vt as (sel ....  ), recursive rt as ( sel....) select ... from rt`, thank you @ravioli